# Bootstrap Modal: How To Open a Modal for one case and disable the same modal for another case using Same Button?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I was coding front end screen for adding **Edit** features over fetched data from database.I have two kinds of data:

1. Uneditable :  status Not = 'yes';  A modal will display
2. Editable :  status = 'yes'; No modal will display.

I used modal before when modal is needed in both cases, but Now you can notice that,modal will open if and only if `status Not = 'yes'`I don't know that.please help me.thanks

```js
var status = 'yes';
$('#edit').click(function() {
   
 if(status == 'yes'){
//No Warning Modal Appear.So your data is Editable.
   $('#myModal').modal('hide');
 }
 else{ 
    //Warning Modal Appear.So your data Not Editable.
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id ='edit'>Edit</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>the data status != 'yes'.Therefore,Warning Modal Appear.So your data Not Editable</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. I am not sure what are you asking here. Do you want modal to display only when a certain condition is true? Or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

If it were me doing this, I would remove `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` and manage the modal display manually.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#edit').click(function(){
        if( conditions == true ) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }else{
            // do nothing
        }
    });
</script>
```